# Incorrect results of Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The commands

```
Integrate[1/(z + Exp[I*t]), {t, 0, 2*Pi}, Assumptions -> Abs[z] == 1]
```

> `(2 \[Pi])/z`

and

```
Integrate[1/(Exp[I*Pi*a] + Exp[I*t]), {t, 0, 2*Pi},  Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[(2*Pi)/E^(I*a*Pi), a > 3]`

produce incorrect results since the integrals (In fact, this is the same integral.) diverge:
for example, the result of

```
Series[ComplexExpand[Im[1/(Exp[I*Pi/4] + Exp[I*t])]], {t, Pi + Pi/4, 1}]
```

> `1/(Sqrt[2] (t-(5 \[Pi])/4))-1/(2 Sqrt[2])-(t-(5 \[Pi])/4)/(12 Sqrt[2])+O[t-(5 \[Pi])/4]^2`

implies the divergence of the above integrals for $z=\exp\left(i \frac \pi 4\right)$ and $a= \frac \pi 4 +2\pi$.

There exists a Cauchy principal value. Unfortunately, the result of

```
Integrate[1/(Exp[I*Pi*a] + Exp[I*t]), {t, 0, 2*Pi}, Assumptions -> a > 0, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[ E^(-I a \[Pi]) ((5 - 2 a) \[Pi] - 2 I Log[-I E^(I a \[Pi])]),  3/2 <= a <= 5/2]`

```
E^(-I a \[Pi]) ((5 - 2 a) \[Pi] - 2 I Log[-I E^(I a \[Pi])]) /. a -> 2
```

> `0`

contradicts

```
NIntegrate[1/(Exp[I*Pi*2] + Exp[I*t]), {t, 0, 2*Pi}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> {Pi}]
```

> `3.14159`

Are there workarounds for the above integrals?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is that the `Integrate` gives the value of the integral along a contour, but not necessarily the one you expected.

****In particular, just because you specify real end points doesn't mean that the contour will lie along the real axis.****

For example, by choosing a specific contour on which to do the integration, I can get different values

```
Integrate[1/(1 + Exp[I*t]), {t, 0, π/2 + I, 3 π/2 + I, 2*Pi}] // FullSimplify
(* 2 π *)

Integrate[1/(1 + Exp[I*t]), {t, 0, π/2 - I, 3 π/2 - I, 2*Pi}] // FullSimplify
(* 0 *)
```

If I specify a value passing through the singularity, it reports that the integral does not converge

```
Integrate[1/(1 + Exp[I*t]), {t, 0, π, 2*Pi}] // FullSimplify
(* Integrate::idiv: Integral of 1/(1+E^(I t)) does not converge on {0,π}. *)
(* Integrate[1/(1 + E^(I t)), {t, 0, π, 2 π}] *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest to the question. First, for concrete `z`, for example, $z=1,i,,...$ s.t. $|z|=1$, `Integrate` produces the correct result. For example, `Integrate[1/(1 + Exp[I*t]), {t, 0, 2*Pi}]` performs an error communication "Integrate::idiv: Integral of 1/(1+E^(I t)) does not converge on {0,2 \[Pi]}." and then returns the input.

Comment: Second, your claim "

I think the answer is that the Integrate gives the value of the integral along a contour, but not necessarily the one you expected.
In particular, just because you specify real end points doesn't mean that the contour will lie along the real axis." is not grounded. Third, how about the Cauchy principal value?.  Sorry, but this is not it.